# use ON DUPLICATE KEY for table that have two primary key

Tags: mysql, on-duplicate-key

I have a table with 2 primary keys(`user_id`,`post_id`)
I want to insert row only if table havn't a row with this `user id` and `post id` 
And if previous data exist for this keys , only that row update with the new data
I wrote this query:

```
INSERT INTO trust_list(`user_id`,`post_id`,`post_per`,`comment_per`,`cat_per`)
VALUES (7,1,'000','000','000') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `post_per`='000',`comment_per`='000',`cat_per`='000'
```

For example if this row exist in the table:

- user_id:5
- post_id:1
- post_per:001
- comment_per:111
- cat_per:101

Then ,when i  execute the above query , mysql update this row,only because `post_id` of this row is "1"
Whereas mysql should not update this row .
I don't understand what's the problem.

```
DESC trust_list
```

result of above query is:

```
Field       Type        Null    Key     Default     Extra
user_id     int(11)    NO       PRI     NULL    
post_id     int(4)     NO       PRI     NULL    
post_per    tinytext   YES              NULL    
comment_per tinytext   YES              NULL    
cat_per     tinytext   YES              NULL
```

=================

Thanks to all of my  friends
When i decide to drop table and ceate it again ,I get an export from this table
and review the `.sql` file,i see this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `trust_list` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `post_per` tinytext COLLATE utf8_estonian_ci ,
  `comment_per` tinytext COLLATE utf8_estonian_ci ,
  `cat_per` tinytext COLLATE utf8_estonian_ci ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idea_id`,`user_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idea_id` (`idea_id`)
)
```

apparently , problem is from the UNIQUE KEY ,I remove it from file ,and then drop `trust_list` table ,and then import .sql file
So with this ,my problem solved
Thanks again

Comment: can you post the result of this statement: `DESC trust_list`.

Comment: Yes,sure,i added it to the post

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is your understanding of primary key. You can't have two primary keys in the table, only one. What you have probably is a primary key that consists of two columns. In that case you only get a key violation when both columns match.

Solution:

Introduce unique indices for both columns. Or - better - change the primary key to be only one of the two columns and set the other column to have a unique index.

Thanks to peterem here is the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9f4ff/1/0) with my solution.

Comment: I think it's the opposite. He wants to allow the insert, but he's getting a duplicate key because he's incorrectly declared `post_id` as a unique key by itself.

Comment: could be. In that case the answer of peterm will help the OP

Comment: I want to have both primary key ,mean user_id and post_id with together be a Perimary Key

Comment: fine, then peterm's answer was what you were looking for. I suggest you accept his answer then to  signal that you are not looking further for other solutions.

Answer (score 2):

There is something wrong with your table schema.

Assuming that your schema defined something like this

```
CREATE TABLE trust_list(
  `user_id` int,
  `post_id` int,
  `post_per` varchar(12),
  `comment_per` varchar(12),
  `cat_per`varchar(12),
PRIMARY KEY(`user_id`, `post_id`)
);
```

here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/040cf7/1)** that demonstrates that your `INSERT` statement works on it just fine.

*Consider to show your `CREATE TABLE` statement to help you find the problem, or just change PK as showed.*

Comment: Thanks,at the first time i ceate this table,`user_id` set as perimary key,But then i execute this query:ALTER TABLE trust_list DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY(user_id, post_id);

Comment: I added the table description ,now i want to know exactly what's the problem,can you help me to find the problem??

Comment: @user2273788 You don't have to have problems with the table schema posted. I've created **[sqlfidle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/62a02/1)** for you with your exact table definition. It works just fine.